# Why is C# XDocument.Descendants() not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

An example of my XML:

```
<data>
    <Balance>
      <LocationName>Locatie 1</LocationName>
      <Latitude>39.74</Latitude>
      <Longitude>-104.99</Longitude> 
         <RTI>
            <Container>12</Container>
            <Pallet>54</Pallet>
        </RTI>
    </Balance>
    // Lots more Balance nodes
</data>
```

And my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Content/saldotracking.xml");
        var balances = doc.Descendants("Data");

        foreach (var b in balances)
        {
            if (b.Element("LocationName").Value == id)
            {
                this.LocationName = b.Element("LocationName").Value;
                this.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(b.Element("Longitude").Value);
                this.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(b.Element("Latitude").Value);
                this.pallets = Convert.ToInt16(b.Element("RTI").Element("Pallet").Value);
                this.containers = Convert.ToInt16(b.Element("RTI").Element("Container").Value);
            }
        }
```

According to the debugger, the value "b" holds the entire XML document, not a single Balance node. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to read all the descendants of a Balance node of which the value of the LocationName node equals a String parameter. Can someone help please?

Comment: Your document doesn't have any `Data` elements in it. It has a single `data` element, but that's not the same... and even if you asked for `data`, that doesn't have a `LocationName` element... it has a `Balance` element. Perhaps you wanted `var balances = doc.Descendants("Balance")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your variable name and usage, you are not using [`Descendants(string XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) properly.

> ```
> public IEnumerable<XElement> Descendants(
>     XName name
> )
> ```
>
> Returns a filtered collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order. *Only elements that have a matching* `XName` *are included in the collection*.

`doc.Descendants("Data")` will give you all descendants with an *element name* of `Data`, not all descendants *of* the `Data` element.

I suspect you want:

```
    var balances = doc.Descendants("Balance");
```

which means "give me all descendants of the document element that have an element name of `"Balance"`

Answer (score 2):

if you want read descendants of a Balance node , then use below statement

var balances = doc.Descendants("Balance");

it will load all elements with "Balances"

Comment: Thanks, I misread the documentation for this function. I thought you had to enter the name of the node of which you want all the descendants. Instead, you have to enter the name of all the descendants you want.

Comment: Also use XElement, which is much faster compare to XDocument. 


Sample Code : 



XElement doc = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Content/saldotracking.xml");
        var balances = doc.Descendants("Balance");